# When is the lattice of all normal subgroups of a group atomic?

Tags: group-theory, lattice-orders, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group. The lattice of all subgroups of $G$ is [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(order_theory)#Atomic_orderings) if and only if $G$ is torsion. The atoms are subgroups generated by elements of prime order. Is there a similar condition for the lattice of all normal subgroups of $G$?